# Chrome/Safari drag a link into ckeditor not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, ckeditor

In the application there is ckeditor to input rich text from the user and there are few links on the webpage. Now If I drag the link into ckeditor all the attributes like 'id', 'class', 'href' are also copied along with the link while using firefox. However If I do the same thing using chrome/safari then link is dragged into the editor but the attributes are not copied. I want these attributes to be copied along with link while dropped into the ckeditor.